# Why Chrome on Android and Firefox on Android are removing "../" sequence from the URL?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, browser, android

When I tried to open https://github.com/../ in Google Chrome, it had sliently redirect me to https://github.com/ and when I tried to open http://qwertyuiopqwertyuiopqwertyuiop11111.com/../ , which is not exist, Google Chrome sliently redirected me to http://qwertyuiopqwertyuiopqwertyuiop11111.com/ .
When I had up a Netcat server on 127.0.0.1:8000 and opened in browser http://127.0.0.1:8000/../ , Netcat showed me in logs:

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: 127.0.0.1:8000
Connection: keep-alive
sec-ch-ua: "Google Chrome";v="105", "Not)A;Brand";v="8", "Chromium";v="105"
sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
sec-ch-ua-platform: "Android"
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 9; K21) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/105.0.0.0 Safari/537.36
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9
Sec-Fetch-Site: none
Sec-Fetch-Mode: navigate
Sec-Fetch-User: ?1
Sec-Fetch-Dest: document
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: ru-RU,ru;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7
```

I tried to find something in Chrome Flags and Firefox Flags, but did not found something helpful.
Why it's happenning?

Comment: Nice research! The netcat test is a great idea.

Comment: I'm no expert at this, but you're trying to send a relative path. From RFC 3986 "The path segments "." and "..", also known as dot-segments, are
   defined for relative reference within the path name hierarchy.  They
   are intended for use at the beginning of a relative-path reference
   (Section 4.2) to indicate relative position within the hierarchical
   tree of names.  This is similar to their role within some operating
   systems' file directory structures to indicate the current directory
   and parent directory, respectively.  [contd…]

Comment: […contd] "However, unlike in a file
   system, these dot-segments are only interpreted within the URI path
   hierarchy and are removed as part of the resolution process" https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#page-22 So, if I read that correctly, it is expected behaviour.

Comment: some webservers in the past incorrectly treated those `..` beyond the root of the URI, allowing access to the real file system in the server which is a serious security issue

Comment: @phuclv, I tried to do ethical security test on some site (I won't name it)

Comment: @Tetsujin, you can post your comments as an answer. One more question: querying with netcat worked without redirects. How to say browser to don't redirect me to path without ../ ?

Comment: @VadSim Don't use a browser. curl is the first tool that comes to mind. As a last resort make a request with netcat.

Comment: I tried this on Chrome for Windows, and the tooltip for the links with `../` is already the same as the one without, so I guess Chrome does URL sanitation internally.